# Admob Interstitial and the dismissing statusbar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, admob, statusbar

i've got a little annoying problem:

I have to display an interstitial every xxx seconds. The App has no navigation controller.

Sometimes, when the interstitial shows up, the statusbar disappears and i have no glue why and how to fix ist.

```
class InterstitialController: NSObject, GADInterstitialDelegate  {

static var shared = InterstitialController()

var view: UIViewController?

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

func loadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial

}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial = loadInterstitial()
    view?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override init() {
    super.init()
    interstitial = loadInterstitial()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 800000, repeats: true, block: { _ in
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            guard let v = self.view else { return }
            self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: v)
        } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }
    })
}
```

In viewWillAppear of every controller, the view property above is set to "self".

Best regards,
Pascal

Comment: well, I've got this problem too so I did some workaround which may not be neat way but since it is not important job.

Comment: I did method swizzling viewWIllAppear, in there I put this code "UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false" to guarantee always show status bar.

Comment: FYI, I got my job done with this workaround.